# Can you nest columns/column in a gutenberg custom template?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, react

I am trying to nest a core columns within a core/columns /core/column template. I keep getting an error that block can't render. However looking at my code it looks fine. [I've simplified the code] So, I am wondering, can it be done?

Here is the code

```
      const TEMPLATE = [['core/cover',{}],[
            ['core/columns',{className:'test1'}],[
            ['core/column',{className: 'test2'}], [
                ['core/columns',{className: 'test3'}], [
                    ['core/column',{className: 'test4'}], [
                        ['core/image',{}],
                    ],
                    ['core/column',{className: 'test5'}], [
                        ['core/heading',{}],
                        ['core/paragraph',{}],
                    ]
                ],
                ['core/columns',{className: 'test3'}], [
                    ['core/column',{className: 'test4'}], [
                        ['core/image',{}],
                    ],
                    ['core/column',{className: 'test5'}], [
                        ['core/heading',{}],
                        ['core/paragraph',{}],
                    ]
                ],
                ['core/columns',{className: 'test3'}], [
                    ['core/column',{className: 'test4'}], [
                        ['core/image',{}],
                    ],
                    ['core/column',{className: 'test5'}], [
                        ['core/heading',{}],
                        ['core/paragraph',{}],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]]];
```

The error I get is 'Your site doesn’t include support for the "core/columns,[object Object]" block. You can leave this block intact or remove it entirely.' What does that mean?

Comment: can you include that error in your question? Do the inner parts work when used on their own?

Comment: @TomJNowell - I've added the errors. Inner parts don't work on their own. However, not sure why as it looks ok mark up wise

Comment: I've also simplified the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe **the cause of the problem has nothing to do with columns and nesting columns within columns**,.

The errors are related to the very first block added in the template and a mixup of the syntax used in the examples on wp.org when reproduced.

If we clear up the indentation you'll see that this is what you did:

```json
[
    [
        'blockname',
        {options}
    ],
    [ child blocks..]
]
```

But .org does this:

```json
[
    [
        'blockname',
        {options},
        [ child blocks..]
    ],
]
```

To make it clearer here is the current example on .org:

```js
const TEMPLATE = [ [ 'core/columns', {}, [
    [ 'core/column', {}, [
        [ 'core/image' ],
    ] ],
    [ 'core/column', {}, [
        [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Enter side content...' } ],
    ] ],
] ] ];
```

And if we expand and fix the indentation:

```js
const TEMPLATE = [
    [
        'core/columns',
        {},
        [
            [
                'core/column',
                {},
                [
                    [ 'core/image' ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'core/column',
                {},
                [
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        { placeholder: 'Enter side content...' }
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

I expect the indentation is non-standard to make it appear shorter/friendlier, but can be misleading if you don't pay careful attention.

Comment: That was it. Thanks.